# length in 2 dimension array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

`var example` is a 2-dimension array. `example.length` will give values like 14.3
But how can I get an integer for the length of `example` in second dimension, like 3 in this case?
 Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the array is homogeneous (which is always the case when such an array is the result of a `getValues()` call in a spreadsheet range for example) you can simply write :

```
example[0].length
```

**EDIT :** a few comments to be more clear ...

The 2D array you get from  `example = range.getValues()` is **always** an array of rows data.

The number of **rows** is represented by `example.length` and the **inner array** length (representing rows content) is always  `example[0].length`, which is actually the **number of columns**

Comment: Like you assumed, this array is from a spreadsheet. An array with length **14.3** would be 3 rows with 14 cells each. `example[0].length` will be **14.0** and not the **3** that I wanted to get.

Comment: no, `example.length` is 14 (14 rows) and `example[0].length` is 3 (3 columns), the common convention when one says 14,3 is to give height, width.

Comment: But as you mention in your question itself, the **first dimension** is `example.length` and the **second dimension** is `example[0].length`, no matter the convention you use ! we are talking about arrays of arrays, the second dimension is obviously the length of the **inner** array